# Pig custom loadFunc always use 1 mapper and 1 inputSplit

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I created a custom loadFunc with a custom `InputFormat` and `RecordReader`.
Whenever the `InputFormat` return more than one input split the `PigSplit` always contains only one input split and use only one mapper.

The implementation is too big to be posted here, but are there any obvious reasons why this might happen ?

Edit: I'm using `pig 0.13` and by adding some logging I found that
the `InputFormat` created by the `Loadfunc` returns a list that contains two input splits and then the `PigInputFormat` uses this list for creating `PigSplits`.

I still can't find out where did Pig omit one of these input splits and only used the first one.

This is the code from PigInputFormat.java ( [src](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.pig/pig/0.12.0-cdh5.1.2/org/apache/pig/backend/hadoop/executionengine/mapReduceLayer/PigInputFormat.java#PigInputFormat.getPigSplits%28java.util.List%2Cint%2Cjava.util.ArrayList%2Clong%2Cboolean%2Corg.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration%29) ) line 273

```
 InputFormat inpFormat = loadFunc.getInputFormat();
 List<InputSplit> oneInputSplits = inpFormat.getSplits(
 HadoopShims.createJobContext(inputSpecificJob.getConfiguration(), jobcontext.getJobID()));
 List<InputSplit> oneInputPigSplits = getPigSplits(oneInputSplits, i, inpTargets.get(i), HadoopShims.getDefaultBlockSize(fs, isFsPath? path: fs.getWorkingDirectory()),
combinable, confClone);
splits.addAll(oneInputPigSplits);
```

I made sure that loadFunc returns 2 input splits, but somehow only one PigSplit is created.
Any clues of how can this be figured out.

Edit 2: So I downloaded the source code for pig 0.13 and compiled it and ran my script and surprisingly it worked fine and used the two splits when I did that, unfortunately I can't do that on the server node.
What I noticed is that the stack trace to create the inputsplits is different between the ready compiled version in cloudera and the downloaded version I compiled.

The cloudera version creates the InputSplits using `org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat` while the downloaded version uses `org.apache.pig.impl.io.ReadToEndLoader`

I'm really getting confused about this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after investigating this, turns out that there is a bug in Pig version <= 0.13 that assumes each InputSplit should have a length ( it always assumes that it's reading from a file ) and because in my case the CustomInputSplit.getLength was returning 0, then pig was taking only the first InputSplit and leaving the others.
Workaround is just return any value in the getLength for the input split.

as I mentioned in the question, the behavior of loading the InputSplits changed after that and there is no need for the work around in these cases.